# How to create hash in C# like in PHP example?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, cryptography

I have to rewrite this php code to c#

```
$sign_params = ['name'=>"John", 'age'=>18];
$client_secret = 'test secret key';
ksort($sign_params); // Sort array by keys
$sign_params_query = http_build_query($sign_params); // Forming string like "param_name1=value&param_name2=value"
$sign = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $sign_params_query, $client_secret, true)), '+/', '-_'), '='); // get hash code
return $sign;
```

Here what I try:

```
    public class apiHelper : MonoBehaviour
{
    const string client_secret = "test secret key";
    public static string checkSign(Dictionary<string, dynamic> fields)
    {
        //* sort by keys
        var list = fields.Keys.ToList();
        list.Sort();
        string sign_params_query = "";
        //* forming string like "param_name1=value&param_name2=value"
        foreach (var key in list)
        {
            sign_params_query = sign_params_query + key + "=" + fields[key];
            if (key != list.Last()) sign_params_query = sign_params_query + "&";
        }
        //* get hash code
        string sign = System.Convert.ToBase64String(GetHash(sign_params_query, client_secret));
        char[] charsToTrim = { '=' };
        return sign.Replace("+", "-").TrimEnd(charsToTrim);
    }
    static byte[] GetHash(string url, string key)
    {
        using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)))
        {
            byte[] data = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url));
            return data;
        }
    }

}
```

Well, finally I get different hash than in php example ._. What did I wrong? Its my 1st time with cryptho or smth like that

Comment: What are you getting and what do you expect? Also, why are you trimming the padding and replacing  characters? btw, your replaces are as far as I can see not identical.

Comment: I replaces not identical because of differents between php and c# mechanics.

Comment: I see trouble with strings with chars as "@", but i dunno how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem wath with strings which have special chars. I have to use url_encode c# equivalent to solve it.

Comment: You should post the solution code so that others can be helped by it.